# HTML DOCTYPE fro WAPFORUM mobile Browsers

Tags: html, browser, mobile

How to write HTML Doctype in HTML 5 for MOBILE DISPLAYS..ie

normally it is WAPFORUM ie:

DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"

But HTML5 dont have a doctype rt ??

pls clarify ??

Answer (score 0):

For HTML 5 the doctype is always: (not case sensitive)

```
$<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In HTML 5 the doctype is optional and there are not many cases, where omitting the doctype will cause any changes.

For more infos on doctypes look:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE